# preventDefault() not working on submit in React

Tags: reactjs, forms, page-refresh, preventdefault, onsubmit

I'm currently working in react and have a couple of forms where the onSubmit functions automatically refresh the page even if I use preventDefault(). Im passing the event into the functions as well. Could really use some guidance on why these two forms are having this issue. It hasn't been a problem elsewhere.

Here's the form. Verify is automatically passing e.

```
 <form onSubmit={verify} className='username-password-form'>
      <div className='old-password-container'>
        <label className='old-password-label'>Current Password:</label>
        <input
          className='old-password-input'
          type='password'
          id={`${id}-old-password`}
          value={currentPassword}
          name='currentPassword'
          disabled={disabled}
          onChange={(e) => setCurrentPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <Button className='submit-old' type='submit'>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Here's the verify function called onSubmit

```
const verify = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

const user = {
  username: user_name,
  password: currentPassword,
};

await fetch('http://localhost:3000/login', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(user),
});
setDisabled(true);
```

};

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I'm using a form with a single submit button and an async submit handler where I tried `preventDefault` and then commented it out. They behave as expected.

Comment: @BrianThompson Yeah, I'm pretty confused as to why this is happening. I use this method in a couple other spots on this project and it works as expected in those components

Comment: Just a way around, remove type=submit from button and attach onClick event handler and inside the handler call verify instead of onSubmit. Then you will not need to use preventDefault

Comment: Is `Button` a component? Because of the uppercase `B`. Can you please also add that code? The rest of the component code would be interesting to see if there is an issue. I don't see a problem.